# Try , finally execution flow when return is in try block

Tags: java, return, try-catch, finally

When try , finally combination is used, in try if there is a return statement.Why is finally block executed first?

---

```
class Palindrome
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        System.out.println(Palindrome.test()); 
    }

    public static int test()
    {
        try {  
                //return 0;  
                return 100;
        }  
        finally {  
            System.out.println("finally trumps return.");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code please tell me the flow of execution. I know that finally will be executed mandatorily after the try block.But in try block, return staatement will take the control to main class. In that case how will the control come to finally block?

Comment: in less amount of effort you could have verified it manually

Comment: @JigarJoshi: How do you verify a "why" question?

Comment: The finally block will always be executed if you enter the try block.  Them's the rules.

Comment: If you want to know *how*, dump the bytecodes.

Answer (score 7):

What do you mean by "first"?

The `finally` runs before execution leaves the method. When else should it run? It is, after all, part of the method.

But if you have

```
int x = 1;
try{
   return x;
} finally {
   x = x + 1;
}
```

then the method will still return 1. So the `return` statement does get executed before the `finally` block in a way (to determine the return value).

If the question is why the finally block is executed *at all*, well, that's what they are for: To "finally" run after the "try" block is done, *no matter what*.

> But in try block, return statement will take the control to main class. In that case how will the control come to finally block?

How? Well, that's just how the language (and runtime) work.

Before control flow is returned to the calling method, the finally block is executed.

It technically even has the option to change the return value (by having its own `return` statement), but that is highly discouraged.

Comment: In my code , from the main method, the control is directly going to the finally block. But not into try block. I am confused with the flow of execution.Ideally when return statement is in the try block, the control should move out of the try block right?

Comment: It goes into the `try` block first. That is why the method returns `100`. Where else would that number come from? Put another `println` before the `return`. It will print before the one from the `finally` block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that I 'm looking for - Before control flow is returned to the calling method, the finally block is executed

Comment: The output for the above code is 
finally trumps return.
100

My question is why is it printing the SOP that is in finally block prior to the try block .

Comment: There is no printing in your try block. You print from the calling method (and that happens after the method returns, after the finally block).

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Finally block is to design to always execute:

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This
>   ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected
>   exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception
>   handling — **it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code
>   accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break**. Putting cleanup
>   code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no
>   exceptions are anticipated.

If you return in try block and code in finally block is not executed, this is not "always executes".

This makes code more readable if we do something necessary in finally block like unlock lock ,cleanup resources,which prevent some other new programmer(or yourself) add some code that returns or introduces exceptions in try block but without cleaning up the resources.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = getInpustStreamFromNetwork();
        int i = 1 / 0;// 1. Intruduces exceptions
        return;// 2. returns before clean up resources
    } finally {
        is.close();// clean up resources is important, so it is a good practice to put it into finally block even though there is no exceptions to catch.
        System.out.println("no matter #1 or #2 ,this will be executed\n,");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's the definition of a finally block. It always happens, regardless of how the block is exited. Finally blocks exist for operations that SHOULD always be performed, like closing open streams and cleaning up socket connections. No matter how the block is exited, the code within the finally block should always be performed. If you want to skip code if the try block is exited successfully, then it belongs in a catch() block with an appropriate exception type.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This
>   ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected
>   exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception
>   handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code
>   accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting cleanup
>   code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no
>   exceptions are anticipated

There are some cases were the finally block may not execute.  Follow the link to see what those are.

Thus the answer to your question is by design.  Java is designed to work that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any design pattern involved for this design ?

Comment: NOthing you do.  It is how the language is designed to operate by SUn now Oracle.